# Rings: A question about "restrictions" to sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let S be a subset of X. Let R be the ring of real-valued functions on X, and let I be the set of real-valued functions on X whose restriction to S is zero. Show that I is an ideal in R.

I have a question about the wording: "let R be the ring of real valued functions ON X" What does this mean in particular?

Also, "...be the set of real valued functions whose restriction to S is zero"
What does "restriction to S" mean?

Thanks

Comment: (The set of) real-valued functions on $X$ is the set of all functions from $X$ to the reals.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they mean is that $R = \{f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $|$ $f is a function $\}$. Do they specify how $R$ is made into a ring? Multiplication could be function multiplication and addition could be function addition.

What they mean by $I$ is $I = \{f\in R $|$ f(S) = \{0\}\}$, i.e. the elements of $I$ are the elements in $R$ (which are real valued functions on $X$) that map everything in $S$ to $0\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hm ok, it is not specified how R is made into a ring - it just says it is.

Comment: and thanks for clearing up the second part!

Answer (score 0):

If $f:A \to B$ is a function, and $X \subseteq A$ the restriction of $f$ to $X$, often written $f|_X$ is the function:

$f: X \to B$ given by $f(x) = f(x)$, for any $x \in X$ (such $x$'s are also in $A$, and $f$ is taken to be defined on all of $A$).

For a finite example: suppose $A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and $B = \{c,d\}$ with:

$f(a_1) = c\\f(a_2) = d\\f(a_3) = c.$

If $X = \{a_1,a_3\}$ then $f|_X$ is the function which maps:

$a_1 \mapsto c\\a_3\mapsto c.$

This is a "different" function than $f$, for example $f|_X$ is a constant function, whereas $f$ is not.

In this context, a function "on $A$", means that $A$ is one possible domain of definition for $f$ (other domains larger or smaller than $A$ may be possible, for the same "rule" of associating an domain element (in $A$) with it's VALUE under $f$ ($f(a) \in B$)). For examle, the "squaring function" might be defined on the integers, the positive real numbers, or the field of complex numbers, but would have the same "rule":

$f(x) = x^2$.

The squaring function on the real numbers, might be restricted to the integers.

Of particular interest here, is when $S = \{x\} \subseteq X$.A function $f$ for which $f(x) = 0$ is said to "vanish" on $\{x\}$. $S$ might be a LOT larger:

The function $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $g(x) = 0$, for all $x \in \Bbb R$ (the "constant function zero"), vanishes on all of $\Bbb R$, where a function like:

$f(x) = x^2 - x$ only vanishes on the set $S = \{0,1\}$.

Typically, when $\{f|f: X \to A \text{ is a function }\}$ is a SET of functions, and $A$ has some kind of algebraic structure, one can impose a "point-wise" structure of the same type as $A$ by performing the operations of $A$ on the values of $f$.

So if $a_1 \ast a_2$ "makes sense" in $A$, we can define $\ast$ between two functions $f_1,f_2$ by setting:

$(f_1\ast f_2)(x) = f_1(x) \ast f_2(x)$.

You have been doing this for years without even knowing it:

If $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ are the functions:

$f(x) = x$, and $g(x) = 5$, then $f+g$ is the function that takes $x \mapsto x + 5$.